# What is difference between GetResponse and SearchResponse in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently I have reading some old coded written in the company and I did not understand the difference between two classes of ElasticSearch. It looks like GetResponse is trying to fetch data given some constraints that are intrinsic properties of tables like _index, _type, etc. I am not sure if my understanding is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetRequest` is for getting a single document by ID and returns a `GetResponse`.

`SearchRequest` is for sending a search request (with query DSL) and retrieve a `SearchResponse` containing a set of documents matching the query.